# view object properties is not resetting on re-render of view in ember js

Tags: ember.js

view variable is resetting on re-render of view but view object property not resetting on re-render of view

```
    App.FooviewView = Ember.View.extend({
        flag1:false,
        obj:{flag:false},
        testlist:[1,2,3],
        actions:{
            test:function(){
                this.set('flag1',true)
                this.set('obj.flag1',true)
                this.get('testlist').push(4);
            }
        }
    })
```

suppose i have render the view and click on mentioned action to set properties. 
and on re render of view flag1 is resetting to false but obj.flag is remains true. why is like that... help pls.

Comment: array is also not resetting on re-render of view

Comment: Which version of Ember are you using and what is your need for Views?

Comment: you say the array is not resetting, but you don't have an array in the sample

Comment: beware that if you declare objects and arrays as properties (`obj` in your example), they will be shared between instances of the prototype.

Comment: i am using Ember  : 1.12.0

Comment: Have you tried:  `this.get('obj').flag = true;`? Since you have a javascritp object and not a record or anything, you should access it like an object...